# Fetch error from ReactJS api to NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

Whenever I try to do a fetch to my backend's provider redirect and I get this error:

```
 Access to fetch at 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fredirect&client_id=2268945580076698' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook') from origin 'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I already have in my backend:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin:"http://localhost:4000",
    methods:"GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials:true
}))

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
    next()
})
```

What I want is for the Frontend to receive the "Hello World" it's sending as JSON data and utilize it.

CODE:

**Backend.jsx**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"

const Backend =  () => {

    const [data,setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{

        const url = "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook"

        fetch(url)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => setData({data}))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
    },[])

    console.log(data)

    return(<p>{data}</p>)
}

export default Backend
```

**auth-facebook.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const passport = require('passport')

router.get("/facebook", passport.authenticate('facebook'))
router.get("/facebook/redirect", passport.authenticate('facebook'), (req,res)=>{
    res.json({message:"Hello world"})
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Look into express CORS middleware to specify where requests are allowed from: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Is there no way to send data from a successful authentication from the backend to the frontend?